# Python tkinter binding - Callback error

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am using python 2.7 in Unix. I want a tkinter canvas that allows user to draw some picture on it. I used the Motion event of tkinter binding. But in that if I release the mouse button and redraw something on it, it throws callback exception, though it is able to recognize the change and allows drawing continuously. I dont want that error being shown. Can someone help me out with this?

Thanks.

```
def paint(event):
    python_black = "#000000"
    x1, y1 = ( event.x - 30 ), ( event.y - 30 )
    x2, y2 = ( event.x + 30  ), ( event.y + 30 )
    w.create_oval( x1, y1, x2, y2, fill = python_black )
    w.update()
    draw_image(x1,x2,y1,y2)

master = Tk()
master.title( "Painting using mouse" )
w = Canvas(master,width=512,height=512)
w.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
master.bind( "<B1-Motion>", paint )
```

Comment: Do you reliaze that probably nobody can help you with your code if you don't post your code? :-)

Comment: Its a function i am calling and that is working fine. I want to know if motion event works only with single time press and move.

Comment: If the `draw_image` method is not relevant, please remove it, to avoid confusion. Also, I seem not to get a callback error at all (just a name error, as I realize now). Could you modify the code to the version that yields the error?

Answer (score 0):

What is `draw_image(x1,x2,y1,y2)` supposed to do? Maybe this is left over from an earlier version of the code?

Remove that line, and it works fine.

Comment: Its is function that is defined but the error is with using motion event only. Does motion event work only with single time click and draw? Or I can release the mouse and continue drawing?

Comment: Not sure I understood the question. Do you want to use a different mouse event for drawing? Do you want to draw circles on mouse-release, or without having to press a mouse button at all? Tested with `<B1-ButtonRelease>` and `<Motion>`, both work as well.

Comment: @user2566909 I think now I get it... you want to press the mouse to enter "drawing mode", then move the mouse without having a button pressed to draw, until pressed again?

Comment: I want to draw picture with left button of mouse no matter I draw it with or without releasing the mouse. Only after closing the widget window it should do some task. But what happens is if i release mouse and redraw it starts throwing callback errors, but anyhow it gives proper result. I dont want it to show error.

Comment: Please post the code that actually produces the error, otherwise I don't think I can understand, much less reproduce your problem.